# Multiple parts of ternary opperators interaction

Tags: c, ternary-operator

This prints `4`. Why?

I'm aware how ternary operators work but this makes it complicated.

```
printf("%d", 0 ? 1 ? 2 : 3 : 4 );
```

Also this prints `d`.
???

```
int x=0, y=1 ;
printf( "d", x ? y ? x : y : x ) ;
```

Comment: If you ask "why", you should tell us why you think it should not be like that.

Comment: I am asking because i dont know . I never claimed that the print value is false or correct.

Comment: Once answers come in, it is bad form on SO to delete parts of the question.  Post rolled back.

Comment: Note that for some obscure reasons, the PHP guys thought it would be a good idea to reverse the associativity of the ternary conditional operator cf. C, C++, C#, and Java. In your case though, this doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first one, its a "Nested" terenary operator. I would put parentheses around it to make it more decodable. Consider `0 ? 1 ? 2 : 3 : 4`, Lets transform this to `0 ? (1 ? 2 : 3) : (4)`  is `0` ? the else part executes which is `4`

For the second you are missing the `%d`

Answer (score 1):

Break it down with `if..else` statement

```
if(0){
    if(1)
        printf("%d\n", 2); 
    else
        printf("%d\n", 3);
} 
else
    printf("%d\n", 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
0 ? 1 ? 2 : 3 : 4
```

parsed as a

```
(0 ? (1 ? 2 : 3) : 4)
```

So, you got output as a `4` .

Answer (score 1):

That indeed should print 4. A ternary operator works as follows:

`(condition) ? expression1 : expression2`

If condition evaluates to true `expression1` is returned, and otherwise `expression2` is returned.
In your case the structure is as follows:

`0?(1?2:3):4` i.e Here `1?2:3` is expression1, `4` is the expression2 and the in place of condition we have `0`. As you may know `0` in a condition evaluates to false and any non-zero value evaluates to true.
So here since the condition is false (i.e `0`) expression2(`4`) is returned.

Answer (score 1):

Ternary operators is like if else. If you add parentheses to your code, things get simpler:

```
0 ? (1 ? 2 : 3) : 4
```

Remember that in C zero means false, all non-zero means true. So above statement fails at test and returns its third part, that is 4.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%d", 0 ? 1 ? 2 : 3 : 4 );
```

Here format specifier is "%d" so it's printing the correct value that is 4.
but, in

```
int x=0, y=1 ;
printf( "d", x ? y ? x : y : x ) ;
```

here no format specifier mentioned so it's just printed the "d" and ignored other parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple ternary operator in the statement
`printf("%d", 0 ? 1 ? 2 : 3 : 4 );`

And when ever same operator comes multiple times we used to check `associativity` which is from `Right` to `Left` for ternary operator i.e first solves `right most ternary opeartor`. Or you can see this in `man 1 operator`

First pick right most ternary operator  `1 ? 2 : 3`  which results in `2`. Now `3` gone.

Now it becomes `0 ?  2 : 4`  which results in `4`. That's why it prints `4`.

**Note :-**  As other's said, with a right associative ternary operator, you can stack them and build an `if-else` expression, like this:

`if(0){ 
if(1)
 printf("%d\n", 2); 
else 
printf("%d\n", 3); 
} 
else 
printf("%d\n", 4);`

Comment: Right-associativity is not relevant, because there is only one possible way to parse this. Right-associativity matters for `a?b:c?d:e` which could be parsed in two different ways.

Comment: i saw a comment on a deleted answer and he said assosiativity isnt relative in this case but only in this `a?b:c?d:e`.I m not saying u are wrong im just asking.^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: missclick.i reloaded page and it appeared on top.

Comment: It matters @interjay otherwise why one would have added in man page.

Comment: Of course it matters in some cases, I even gave an example of one such case. It doesn't matter in OP's code.

Comment: so in ur case the c?d:e will execute first and the value from this output will be the expresion 2 for the a?b:exp2?if thats the case i believe you are right in this one and its 2 diffrent things